# Restricting access via IP-ranges (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address, subnet

Basically, I aim to allow my user to specify an ip range for access to a test. So lets say these values are stored in my database:

from: 148.197.34.112

To: 148.197.34.255

Are there any functions of which I can use to convert these ip addresses into numbers for comparison?

So obviously if a user tries to load a page...if his IP is not within an ip range, re-direct them.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If somebody can provide code to generate range from IPv6 addresses too, I will appreciate.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to do this in PHP? Because you could just as easily do this in your webserver configuration...

Comment: I don't have access to webserver config - its a uni project. thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ip2long()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function will do the job for a IPv4 address.

To convert an IPv6 address to a 128-bit integer, use the [inet_pton()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) function.

Comment: merci :D out of interest is there such a thing for dealing with IPv6 addresses?

Answer (score 1):

If values stored in database exactly in this format, then you can use [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) function (for mysql, at least) and ip2long() in php.

```
$iplong=ip2long($ip);
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ips WHERE INET_ATON(ip_from)<='".$iplong."' AND INET_ATON(ip_to)>='".$iplong."' LIMIT 0,1");
```

But, of course, it will be much better to store long values in DB, instead of pure IP.